# React state updating through child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this issue working on a project and was able to recreate the issue in this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd3jh1ns/). The state of the parent component seems to be changing when the state of the the child component is updated, what is going on here?

Parent class:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {objectList:[
        {value1:1}
    ]}
}


render(){
    return <div>
        { this.state.objectList.map(object=>{
        return <ChildComponent object={object} />
    })}
    <button onClick={()=>{console.log(this.state.objectList[0].value1)}}>print value</button>
    </div>

}
```

Child class:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {object:this.props.object}
}

render(){
    return <button onClick={()=>{this.updateObject()}}>+1</button>
}

updateObject(){
    let object = this.state.object
    object.value1+=1
    this.setState({object})
}
```

}

Comment: You're modifying the state directly, which you aren't supposed to do. Use `let object = { ...this.state.object };` instead.

Comment: Besides mutating the state like already pointed, you're never `binding` `updateObject` to your component's instance

Comment: arrow functions in render make it so you dont have to bind [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the parent state. You should create a whole new object to avoid this problem. Something like this should work:

```
updateObject(){
    let object = {...this.state.object, value1: this.state.object.value1 + 1};
    this.setState({object})
}
```

Comment: To elaborate, here is an article that goes into why mutating the state directly is problematic : https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

TLDR; : mutating the state directly is not considered a change requiring a re-render by React.